# Redirecting old sef link to new sef link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect old link to new link with 301 .htaccess

Sample:1

> Old link>>**hatay**-ili-firmalari31.html
>
> New link>>firmalar/**hatay**

Sample:2

> Old link>>**izmir**-ili-firmalari35.html
>
> New link>>firmalar/**izmir**

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
##i dont know what to do
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following rule for multiple urls :

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^([^-]+)-ili-firmalari[0-9]+\.html$  /firmalar/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^hatay-ili-firmalari31\.html$  firmalar/hatay  [R=301]
RewriteRule    ^izmir-ili-firmalari35\.html$  firmalar/izmir  [R=301]
```

---

Learn more about [RewriteEngine](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html)